# TiViewProxy and view creation

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I'm working on a titanium module.

Little bit confused about the **`TiViewProxy`**.

Why we are using `-(void)setColor_:(id)color` such methods (_ in methods) in ViewProxy ?

If we didn't write any such methods what happens when we call:

```
myModule.createView({
  color : 'red'
});
```

If I didn't passed any argument on my `createView()` method how my view creation code will work on my module.

Means:

I'm just creating my view in my app.js like:

```
myModule.createView();
```

I'm handling the view creation code inside:

```
-(void)setColor_:(id)color
{
}
```

If I'm not passing any argument how my view is created ? Will it work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll explain the various moving parts. It's all part of the platform, so not critical that you know how it works. Knowing that it does this for you is important, though. So...

When you call myModule.createView(), the platform looks for a child of your module that matches certain constraints. Let me expand that statement by looking at the `ti.pageflip` module. `myModule`'s class is `TiPageflipModule`. When I call `myModule.createView()`, the platform will look for `TiPageflipViewProxy` so it can instantiate it. `TiPageflip` comes from the module's name, minus "Module". "View" comes from `createView`. "Proxy" is tagged on because that's how we get from JavaScript to native. The `TiPageflipViewProxy` creates a native view, `TiPageflipView`. The proxy handles interactions between JavaScript and the native view. Make sense so far?

Part of the naming convention for exposed properties is that they are suffixed with an `_`. The platform looks for these methods, and calls each of them set in the creation dictionary `createView({ whatever: 'value' })` as well as the property `view.whatever = 'value';` or the method `view.setWhatever('value')`. (Search for the word "underscore" in the iOS mod dev guide, it only occurs once, to read more: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/iOS+Module+Development+Guide).

Because you aren't defining createView, the platform is doing it for you, and it handles `createView()` just the same as `createView({})`. It's an optional param. That's just by definition.

Comment: just one question: if I didn't passed any argument will it call my `setColor_` method ?

Comment: You better not be baiting me to say something wrong, when you know it's behaving a certain way. :P No, setColor_ should not be called.

Comment: Thanks dude for your answer. I asked it because I wrote a method for creating and adding a special control (view) to TiView class and called the method in `setColor_` method. But when I ran with no argument nothing happened. :)

Comment: *phew* If I remember right, there's a way you can set default values for your properties. That might call the method, even with no arg passed to the constructor. I don't remember how that works at the moment, though. The mod dev guide has lots of examples of these use cases, though: https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/moddevguide/mobile